# After element not showing

Tags: php, css

When I'm using div class = `btn-white` code good working. But here I do not see the pseudo after element. Why is this happening?

**PHP CODE:**

```
<input id="add-todo" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-white" value="'.apply_filters( 'ctdl_add_text', esc_attr__( 'Add To-Do Item', 'cleverness-to-do-list' ) ).'" />
```

**CODE EXAMPLE:**

[Codepen](http://%20https://codepen.io/Alex_Balatsan/pen/XEmPoZ)

Comment: `::after` => `css3` not `:after` => `css2`

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field